# How to Azure API Management (BASIC TIER) with microservices deployed in Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: azure, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-api-management

I want to place **API-Management** in front of **AKS**.

I was following the below-mentioned document to achieve the same. I can't put both of them in a VNET (OPTION 3) because I am using the **Basic Tier** of API-management and it **doesn't have VNET support**.

**Option 2: Install an Ingress Controller** (from the document below) is what I need to achieve, But the steps are not clear in the document.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-kubernetes#option-2-install-an-ingress-controller

Any document or source with the steps required to achieve the same will be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would use this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-basic documentation to create the ingress.

Comment: I am following the same document that you shared above, I am not able to test the ingress from the postman. It is using the CURL command, How I can do the same using Postman?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67411816/azure-aks-test-tls-enabled-ingress-using-postman