# Azure-AKS: Test TLS enabled Ingress using Postman

Tags: azure, curl, postman, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks

I am referring to [following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/ingress-own-tls#test-the-ingress-configuration) document to create an HTTPS ingress controller( use my own TLS certificates ).
I can't understand how do I test the below curl request from the POSTMAN.

```
curl -v -k --resolve demo.azure.com:443:EXTERNAL_IP https://demo.azure.com
```

Comment: what happens when you do a get to that url ?

Comment: I'd reckon this is not possible as per this github issue: [Github.com: Postmanlabs: Postman-app-support: Issues: curl --resolve behaviour](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5129). The workaround for it would be to edit the `/etc/hosts` file or equivalent depending on the OS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting this answer as a community wiki to give more visibility on the github issue in the comments as well as potential workarounds.

Feel free to expand/edit it.

---

As pointed in the github issue:

- *[Github.com: Postmanlabs: Postman-app-support: Issues: curl --resolve behaviour](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/5129)*

> I'm looking for being able to send a GET request to a specific host, other than the hostname specified in the request. To use a quick example - assume [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) resolves to 1.1.1.1; I'd like for the GET [www.mysite.com](http://www.mysite.com) to be sent to 2.2.2.2 instead, without having to modify the hosts file. In effect, I'm looking for the same outcome when using curl --resolve. Is this possible with Postman ?
>
> ---
>
> **Custom resolution is not supported at the moment. We'll track this as a feature request and post any updates here.**

As it can be seen this feature is not yet supported.

As a workaround measure you could try to (as pointed in the github issue):

- Modify the `hosts` file of your operating system (depending on your os it could be either: `/etc/hosts` or `C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts`) to set the domain resolution to the external ip address of your `Ingress controller`

```
EXTERNAL_IP DOMAIN.NAME
```

- Use `Postman` to send the request to the `DOMAIN.NAME` and check if your `Ingress controller` respond with the `self-signed` certificate.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Postman.com](https://www.postman.com/)*
- *[Support.acquia.com: Use curl resolve option to pin a request to an IP address](https://support.acquia.com/hc/en-us/articles/360005257154-Use-cURL-s-resolve-option-to-pin-a-request-to-an-IP-address)*